# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'nonetype' objects in python / sql / flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to pass a column name into the SQL Query just once. This code works fine when ordering but when a button is pressed on the page (which inserts content into a table) this error is thrown.

"cannot concatenate 'str' and 'nonetype' objects"

```
    if request.method == "POST":
    ## DISPLAYING MOVIES ##

    general = db.execute(
        """
        SELECT Movies.Movie_ID, Movies.Name, Movies.Year, Movies.Image
        FROM Movie_Genre
        JOIN Movies ON Movie_Genre.Movie_ID = Movies.Movie_ID
        JOIN Genres ON Movie_Genre.Genre_ID = Genres.Genre_ID
        WHERE Genres.Genre = ? AND Rating_IMDB >= ?
        ORDER BY """+order+""";
        """, 
        (str(selectedGenre), rating)
        )
    basic = general.fetchall()
```

This is the code which causes the error to be shown.. The code is executed when a user presses the 'favourite' button.

```
try:
    clicked = request.get_json(['data'])
    user = db.execute(
        """
        SELECT User_ID
        FROM Users
        WHERE Username = ?;
        """,
        (user_name,)
        )

    userID = user.fetchone()[0]

    user_favs = db.execute(
        """
        INSERT INTO User_Favs
        VALUES (?,?);
        """,
        (userID, clicked,)
        )
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    gc.collect()
except:
    pass
```

**EDIT**

This is where order is coming from, it is almost never 'None'

```
order = request.form.get('order')
while order:
    if order == "Newest":
        order = "Year DESC"
        break 
    elif order == "Oldest":
        order = "Year ASC"
        break
    elif order == "Best":
        order = "Rating_IMDB DESC"
        break
    elif order == "Worst":
        order = "Rating_IMDB ASC"
        break
    else:
        order == ''
        break
```

If the problem was with the concatenation then the ordering query wouldnt work on the website, but it does. The error only occurs when I press the 'favourite' button. Which inserts data into the database.

Comment: Your blanket except is not going to be very informative

Comment: Okay, so the error is showing as "400: Bad Request". Thanks for pointing that out btw

Comment: So where's `order` coming from, as it is clearly `None` (that's what the error says). I assume all the snippets originate from the same view function. You could for example check if `order is None` and act accordingly.

Comment: What is the type of 'order' and where does its value get set? Also, 'order' is a keyword to the SQL parser in SQLite

Comment: I have edited the question. 'order' is almost never 'None'. It works just fine with the query except for when I press the favourite button and it attempts to insert into the database.

Comment: `=` is not the same as `==`

Comment: Remove the `while order:`. This also allows you to remove the `break`s. When `order` isn't included in the POST, it's None and your while loop doesn't run, leaving `order` untouched.

Comment: I added a flash after the POST and order was not 'None'.

Answer (score 0):

In the else clause you wrote:

```
    else:
        order == ''
        break
```

Instead of:

```
    else:
        order = ''
        break
```

Also, the `while` clause is redundant as the code in that block will only run once (because of the `break`s in each condition). And if the `request.form.get('order')` returns `None`, you won't even get to that code.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. I changed it, and the result is still the same. I flashed the variable before the query and it does not appear to be 'None'

Comment: What does `while order` suppose to do?

Comment: Add some debugging prints in some strategic points like in the while clause before and after the ifs

Comment: While order goes through order and changes its values depending on what it was equal to when the value was obtained from the HTML. If that makes sense..

Comment: It seems you don't need it. `while` intention is to iterate a number of times over a block of code. But here it seems as if you only need it to run once. I believe order is `None` before it gets to the `while` clause. Try to print `order` right after you get it from the request.

Comment: Anyway you should lose the `while` clause and it will work fine. I will edit my answer.